# LocalStorage variable to work across tabs with Windows.SetTimeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have the below JS code. This code basically starts a timer based on variables passed in when the page loads. This works fine on one tab. So basically if different section of the page are opened in different tabs  based on the last server visit I want to refresh the timeout variable so that when the time ends the user is signed out from all the tabs and not just the current tab.

I want this:

```
window.setTimeout(promptToExtendSession, localStorage.getItem("secondsBeforePrompt1") * 1000);
```

to be refreshed in all the tabs if the

```
localStorage.getItem("secondsBeforePrompt1")
```

gets updated through any tab.

I am assigning values to the LocalSTorage variable on the server side.

```
   var SessionManager = function() { 
            var endSession = function() {
                $('#sessionTimeOutModal').modal('hide');
                location.href = expireSessionUrl;
            };             



            var startSessionManager = function () {                
                promptToExtendSessionTimeoutId =
                    window.setTimeout(promptToExtendSession, localStorage.getItem("secondsBeforePrompt1") * 1000);
            };

            // Public Functions
            return {
                start: function() {
                    startSessionManager();
                },
                extend: function() {
                    refreshSession();
                }
            };
        }();


 SessionManager.start();
```

Comment: You can only access another tab if it was open programmatically. However, since all you need is the timer value, you can set that on the server side. You can also do so with cookies but the user can modify those values.

Comment: Hey..Yes I am setting the values of the timeouts on the server side. The issue is that say you open tab 1 of the page then in Windows.SetTimeout the value gets set to say 30. Now after sometime when you open the page in another tab I want the value to reset and Windows.SetTimeout be refreshed on the first tab as well with the value 30 that comes from the server.

Comment: can use storage events http://html5demos.com/storage-events